# How do I render different partials depending on the screen size in handlebar.js?

Tags: handlebars.js

I am currently working on a project using node.js and handlebar.js.

What I want to implement is to detect the screen size and render other partial.

I don't know what to do with conditional rendering based on screen size in handlebar.js.

I'd appreciate it if you could give me a hint on what to do.

Comment: As screen-size is a client-side property, it sounds like you will need to render _all_ of your screen-size-specific partials and have client-side JavaScript which shows/hides the rendered HTML elements based on the screen-size.